# Bigquery replacing empty results or null values with some 000

Tags: google-bigquery

I see for few dates data is not there, And now for the dates which data doesn't exist, i would like to replace it with zero instead of no results found. I tried as below and got the present output

select trvl_details.strt_dte as cre_dte,
trvl_typ_cde,
coalesce(count(1),0) as createdcount
from project.dataset.tableid JOIN UNNEST(trvl_details)trvl_details
WHERE trvl_details.strt_dte >= "2020-12-24" and trvl_typ_cde='AIR' group by 1,2

[image]

[image]

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#generate_date_array) to create a list of dates and then left join generated list of dates with your results:

```
WITH your_data AS (
  select trvl_details.strt_dte as cre_dte, trvl_typ_cde, coalesce(count(1),0) as createdcount 
  from project.dataset.tableid JOIN UNNEST(trvl_details)trvl_details 
  WHERE trvl_details.strt_dte >= "2020-12-24" and trvl_typ_cde='AIR' 
  group by 1,2
)
SELECT day, your_data.trvl_typ_cde, IFNULL(your_data.createdcount, 0)
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-12-01', '2020-12-31')) as day 
LEFT JOIN your_data 
ON day = your_data.cre_dte
```

Comment: ..It worked. But would like is there a way that we get desired output without using the generate array as  it involves manual provision of dates. .